# I was trying to remove password for the root user of mysql permanently. Got stuck with the below mentioned error

Tags: permissions, mysql, sudo, password, root

I typed below commands in cmd prompt.

```
sudo systemctl stop mysql.service
sudo systemctl status mysql.service
```

**Error**: Unable to type anything and stuck with `lines 1-13/13(END)`
What to do next?

2. If I want to create an user account for any services and give them complete permissions for a single database of those services only. Don't want to use `root` account. How can it be possible to do?

Comment: Edit your post to make both title and question more clear. This is apparently about the root account of mysql, and not about the root account of the Ubuntu system?

Comment: What's the difference between root account of mysql and root account of Ubuntu system?

Comment: What 'steps' are you asking about in part 1? You're showing what looks like the output from a status query. There are no 'steps' in the output.

Comment: https://linuxhint.com/change-mysql-root-password-ubuntu/

I have applied using the URL instructions till STEP-3. After which I cannot able to proceed.

Either I want to exit out of cmd prompt but I can't type anything in cmd prompt or need to complete the tasks as mentioned in the URL but still hanging over there.

Comment: No one here can know what instructions you were trying to execute. You have now provided a link, but it's unreasonable to expect people to go read that link and figure out what you did. Edit your question, show the command you input, and its output. Do not post screenshots, edit the text in.  If you are really asking just how to get out of that status screen, you just type "q".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing... since you say you want to create a user for "any kind of services" but, then that the user should only have permissions to one particular database..

Assuming you're just looking to not type in a pw each time you start SQL, then you may be able to modify the folder that SQL is in with the info in the first 5 paragraphs of this page...

https://smallbusiness.chron.com/give-permissions-ubuntu-33174.html

Comment: The 1st question is bit important. How to resolve the issue after ```END```?

Comment: @PKS21 If you want to exit from that prompt, just press *Q* on keyboard.

Comment: Link only answer

Comment: @Greenonline which link?

Comment: @Liso Will it be a problem or crash to the system, If I press Q?

Comment: @PKS21 From your picture, I think you only toggle service status, shouldn't be a problem at all then.

Comment: @Liso It's fine now when I pressed Q.

Can you let me know about the 2nd point and the difference between root user in ```mysql``` and root account in ```ubuntu```?

Comment: @PKS21 completely independent of each other.  MySQL root user is admin for MySQL.  `root` in Linux is the superuser who can do pretty much anything on the system (and is disabled by default in Ubuntu in lieu of the use of `sudo` by admins instead)

Comment: @ThomasWard Thank you.